# IntelliJ interactive rebase failing

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, rebase

Hello I can do rebase with current branch onto the selected but when I try to do interactive rebase from VCS/git/rebase this is what I am getting:

18:42   Rebase Failed
            cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
            unable to start editor '"C:/Development/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4/jre64/bin/java" -cp "C:/Development/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4/plugins/git4idea/lib/git4idea.jar;C:/Development/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4/lib/xmlrpc-2.0.1.jar;C:/Development/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar" git4idea.rebase.GitRebaseEditorMain 63342'
            Retry

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: How did you exactly do this ? Can you share the steps you followed ?

Comment: I already did. In the menus on the top you go to VCS -> Git -> Rebase and then i select a remote branch with which I want to rebase and click Rebase

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same error; word for word. (Aside from being the commercial version and installed in `Program Files` instead of `Development`.) The odd part is I was running 2019.1.3, so there's no way it should have been running anything in 2018.3.4.

It appears to have been an issue with the in-place upgrade. I uninstalled 2019.1.3 (which interestingly was installed in `C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4/`), reinstalled, and now VCS > Git > Rebase works fine.